# Wrap several stages in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline

In my declarative pipeline I have several stages where Xvfb is not required and several testing stages, where it is.

Is it possible to define a [Jenkins wrapper](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#wrap-general-build-wrapper) ones for several stages? Something like this:

```
  pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {
            stage('Build the context') {
                steps {
                    echo 'No Xvfb here'
                }
            }
            wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1920x1080x24']) {
                stage('Test Suite 1') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Use Xvfb here'
                    }
                }

                stage('Test Suite 2') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Use Xvfb here'
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('cleanup') {
                steps {
                    echo 'No Xvfb here'
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting compilation errors wherever I put the wrap block for several stages:

```
WorkflowScript: 10: Expected a stage @ line 10, column 17.
               wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1920x1080x24'])
```

Comment: as a walk-around you could start XVFB on a stage, and leave it running until you finish testing. not as clean as a wrapper, but it should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `wrap` is a step, we have to call it from a `steps` or `script` context. Only the latter allows us to create nested stages inside of a `wrap` block. Try this:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build the context') {
            steps {
                echo 'No Xvfb here'
            }
        }
        stage('Test Start') {
            steps {
                script {
                    wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1920x1080x24']) {
                        stage('Test Suite 1') {
                            echo 'Use Xvfb here'
                        }

                        stage('Test Suite 2') {
                            echo 'Use Xvfb here'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

The extra stage "Test Start" may look a bit ugly, but it works.

**Note**: There are no `steps` blocks required in the nested test stages, because we are already inside a `script` block, so the same rules as in scripted pipeline apply.